# Google Spreadsheet Find and replace Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I really need a script to perform the following result when there is K present in the a range "B1:B7".

Data is :-

```
 A     B     C
      12.2K
      13.30K
      15.19K
      17.19K
      12
```

The result should be :-

```
 A     B     C
      12200
      133000
      151900
      171900
      12
```

I will really appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 2):

Please try Find and replace with "Search using regular expressions" and Find:

```
^(.+)K
```

Replace with

`=1000* $1`

That is select all (`.` (any character), `+` any number of times) from the start (`^`) up to `K` and replace with `=1000*` plus the selection. `*` here is for multiplication.